# Why is my JLabel never being painted?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, repaint

Firstly, I have looked at all of the other similar posts on here, but none have been able to help. I am writing a game of minesweeper and I am trying to put a Jlabel in the top of my JFrame's borderLayout, and have it show a counter of how many mines are left to be flagged. It needs to be repainted anytime any of my other Jlabels on my grid are clicked. Firstly, with my code as is no text is ever displayed on my header JLabel. The only way I can get text to show up is to put it in my JLabel constructor. That leads me to think that my paintComponent is never being called. I have also placed a call to my headerJabel's repaint method inside of the mouseHandler for the actual grid of my game. That way, if the user clicks on any of the components in the game, the heading JLabel will repaint itself to reflect the user's move.

Basically, why will my JLabel not show anything unless I explicitly put it inside the constructor?

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JLabelCounter extends JLabel {

```
private MinesweeperModel model;
public JLabelCounter(MinesweeperModel myModel)
{
   model = myModel;    

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int minesRemaining = model.numberOfMinesRemaining();
    setText("Mines remaining" + minesRemaining);

}
```

}

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MinesweeperPanel extends JPanel {

 private MinesweeperModel model;
 private JLabelCounter labelCounter;

public MinesweeperPanel(MinesweeperModel myModel, JLabelCounter counter)
{
    model = myModel;
    labelCounter = counter;
    setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
    //addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());

     for(int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            MinesweeperJLabel myJLabel = new MinesweeperJLabel(i,j,myModel);
            myJLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseHandler());
            add(myJLabel);
        }

    }

}

private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {

        MinesweeperJLabel labelClicked = (MinesweeperJLabel)e.getSource();
        int x = labelClicked.getXCoordinate();
        int y = labelClicked.getYCoordinate();
        int buttonClicked = e.getButton();

        if (buttonClicked == 1)
        {
            model.stepOnMine(x,y);
        }
        else if(buttonClicked == 3)
        {
            model.flagMine(x, y);
        }
      repaint(); 
      labelCounter.repaint();


    }
}
```

}

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class MinesweeperFrame  extends JFrame{

public MinesweeperFrame()
{
    MinesweeperModel myModel = new MinesweeperModel();
    setTitle("My Super Awesome Minesweeper Game!");
    Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension screenSize = kit.getScreenSize();
    setSize(screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JLabelCounter counter = new JLabelCounter(myModel);
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    MinesweeperPanel panel = new MinesweeperPanel(myModel,counter);
    contentPane.add(counter,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    contentPane.add(panel);

    setVisible(true);      


}
```

}

With the code as is, It looks as if I don't I even have  JLabel in my header when I run.

Comment: Don't call setText from within the paintComponent, it will cause an invalidation of the component and another repaint request, again and again and ... You get the idea

Comment: Then how do I get the JLabel to show different text that updates with the game?

Comment: See answer - basically, us an observer pattern

Answer (score 3):

Don't call setText from within the paintComponent, it will cause an invalidation of the component and another repaint request, again and again and ... You get the idea

Instead of trying to update the label in the paint method. Ad some kind of listener interface to you model that you can use to update the label.

Basically, when your model changes, it will fire an event, which your label can react to and update it self

Comment: I thought about that, but the user will never actually click on the header. SO a listener attached to the header would never get triggered

Comment: That depends on what it's listening for.  MP didn't say have it listen for a user event, but to listen for a model event.  Your model (however you have it implemented) is all that data and data structure that represents the logic for the game (as separate from the UI); it knows which squares have been cleared, which ones are displaying the number of mines adjacent, that sort of thing.  When the user clicks on one square, I would expect the model to have a listener fired, figure out what other squares' states have changed as a result, and fire a listener for every one of those squares.